# Failed to group by field a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list of 50 first clients in `_db.Clients` and a trade fine of each client in `_db.Fines`.
I want to push those clients to `ClientFineView` model with a `TotalEquity` sum from `_db.Fines`.

But I got this error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

I guess, my group by query is incorrect, so it could not find the selected values. **So what I need to do to solve this problem? I'll be very appreciated**

**LINQ:**

```
IEnumerable<TraderView> clients = await (
                from client in _db.Clients.Take(50)
                join trade in _db.Fines
                    on client.Id equals trade.ClientId
                select new
                {
                    client,
                    trade
                } into clientTrades
                group clientTrades by clientTrades.trade.ClientId into tq
                select new ClientFineView
                {
                    TotalEquity = tq.Sum(x=>x.trade.TotalEquity),
                    Username = tq.FirstOrDefault().client.Username,
                    Email = tq.FirstOrDefault().client.Email,
                    Id = tq.FirstOrDefault().client.Id,
                    Firstname = tq.FirstOrDefault().client.Firstname,
                    Lastname = tq.FirstOrDefault().client.Lastname
                }).ToListAsync();
```

**ClientFineView Model:**

```
public class ClientFineView
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public decimal TotalEquity { get; set; }
    }
```

**Client model**

```
public class Client
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Username { get; set; }

            public string Firstname { get; set; }

            public string Lastname { get; set; }

            public string Password { get; set; }

            public string Email { get; set; }

            public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        }
```

Comment: can you add trade model? 
is client to trade one to one or one to many ?

Comment: @Munzer one to many. `trade` model consist of `ClientId`, `TotalEquity` and others, which aren't used here. Other values, which are used here are taken from `Client` model

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is causing the error

```
                TotalEquity = tq.Sum(x=>x.trade.TotalEquity)
```

if the source is null [sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298138(v=vs.110).aspx#Exceptions) will throw an argument null exception
just add a checking, if count is more than 0 get sum if not set it to 0

```
                TotalEquity = tq.Select(e => e.trade).Count() > 0 ?  tq.Sum(x=>x.trade.TotalEquity) : 0
```

**Update**

in case you still get the error, or you got another error 
try checking the count of tq, because some of clients might have 0 fines, which will return null when you try to use FirstOrDefault() 
so you would add this checking before your select

```
where tq.Count() > 0
select new etc ....
```

Comment: I can not access here `tq.trade.Count()`

Comment: if one to many trade should be list, isn't it ?, post the original client model

Comment: one client and many fines of the same client. And Im trying to sum those fines

Comment: added client model

Comment: Answer updated, are you using entity framework ? if yes why your client doesn't have virtual collection of fines ?

Comment: sorry, but this didn't help. `TotalEquity` isn't null. Nullable are other values from client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154810/discussion-between-lab-lab-and-munzer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. Before the `group by` query, you should first select a `client` and `trade` models together. And then do with them whatever you need.